# Laravel 4 - How to json_decode a field every time its accessed?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

We are storing User preferences as JSON. Since our application acts as an API, responses are returned as JSON as well, but the preferences field is returned as a string. I'd like to make sure this portion of the object is always decoded before any response is sent ie

```
$user->prefs = json_decode($user->prefs);
```

But where? Should I look at "overloading" the User index method? Is this more of a before_filter action? What is *laravel* way of doing this?

Comment: Is `$user` an instance of an Eloquent model?

Comment: Yes it is. We are also using laravel-auth-token, so its being used as a driver as well...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an Eloquent accessor on your model:

```
public function getPreferencesAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value);
}
```

And then you just have to:

```
$user = User::find($id);

return $user->preferences;
```

Look at the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: This answer ended up being the cleanest and it pointed me to the documentation I missed. :)

Comment: I used this solution, but for some reason I each time I try to return this, I get "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given." 
If I try to Log it, it says: "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"
What am I missing? I am using laravel 4.2

Answer (score 0):

I would try writing a method on your model

In your case:

```
public function prefAsJson()
{
    return json_decode($this->prefs);
}
```

You now can use it like this: `$user->prefAsJson()`

// Edit: My first answer was just wrong

Answer (score 0):

The Object-Oriented way of doing this is to not access properties directly, but use 'getters' and 'setters' for your interactions. In that case, you would do:

```
class User {
    public function getPrefs() {
        return json_decode($this->prefs);
    }
}
```